# PDO prepare working when i reload the second time the page

Tags: php, json, pdo

output JSON is [here](http://bluewingholidays.com/xxxxx.php) .when i reload the second time it has new recodes.but when i update the first time it does not have recodes

```
<?php

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db', "user", "pass");
        foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * FROM `jos_jea_towns` LIMIT 0, 500 ') as $row) {
           echo '<pre>' . json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).'</pre>';

        }
        $insertObject = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `jos_jea_towns` (id, value) VALUES (:id, :value)");
    $insertObject->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $insertObject->bindParam(':value', $value);

    // insert one row
    $id = 433;
    $value = 'yyy';
    $insertObject->execute();

    // insert another row with different values
    $id = 434;
    $value = 'xxx';
    $insertObject->execute();

    // insert another row with different values
    $id = 435;
    $value = 'Samitha';
    $insertObject->execute();

        $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }



    ?>
```

How is this PDO prepare working or is there any problem with my JSON file?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *are* selecting first, and updating later. So the first time, you select, before you've added the records, then you add the records.

On the second reload, you've already added the records (from the previous iteration), and so the inserted records are displayed.

---

To solve, insert first, and select after. That way you can see the changes you've just made.